# Avoid duplication of char array used in NSMutableData

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
[self.commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x57\x80\x31" length:sizeof("\x1d\x57\x80\x31") - 1];
```

And I want to avoid duplicating the char array like:

```
- (void)appendBytes:(char *)bytes
{
    [self.commands appendBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
}
```

Then use it like:

```
[self appendBytes:"\x1d\x57\x80\x31"];
```

Well, that's the idea but my knowledge is almost zero by now.